# Mongoose: Try finding a document with multiple conditions stored in an array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

What I am trying to achieve is to find a document by its name and the language.

[image: Data in MongoDB]

My current attempt looks like the following one:

```
Model.find({"name.language": languageIso2, "name.value": { "$regex": search, "$options": "i" }}, (error, SpecialConditons) => {...})
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, because of the following case:

lets say the language is "gb" and you use "a" as a filter for the name, this would send you the model shown in the picture above, because the array "name" contains both (1) the language "gb" and (2) the "a" in the object containing the Finnish translation "Touretten syndrooma".

What I want to achieve is to look for the object that contains "gb" as a language and if the object containing the "gb" also includes an "a" in the value field then it should send me the model back. In this case the value for "gb" doesn't contain an "a", so it should not send it back.

Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: try `$elemMatch` operator to match elements in same object. `{ name: { $elemMatch: { language: "gb", value: { "$regex": search, "$options": "i" } } } }`